# Change base font size for tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, fontsize

I copied several tikzpictures from an article with 11pt base font size to a poster with 25pt base font size. This means that the text within the tikz image is way too large, and I was not able to scale text and image independently. Is it possible to change the base font size of the tikz image, so that I don't have to adapt every text within the image? (I furthermore have the problem, that even \tiny is too large for some texts)

If not, could you suggest any other solution? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to add `\usepackage{fontsize}`. Then add `\changefontsize{25}` either in your preamble or as the first line in document body. I suspect the font in your LaTeX file is customised outside a document class. Hence, nodes in `tikz` still use the standard font defined in a document class.

In the example below, texts in `tikz` are correctly typeset using the same font as in document class

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fontsize}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}


\begin{document}
\changefontsize{18}
\kant[1][1]

\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style = {draw, outer sep=6pt}]
    \node [above,font=\LARGE] {LARGE};
    \node [below] {Document font};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\kant[1][3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT. There are a few recommendations from the author of the [fontsize](https://ctan.org/pkg/fontsize) package, which might be important for you.